# JSON duplicated object

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting data from a json that I'd like to display as text for buttons, however, what I'm getting is duplicated buttons on top of each other. What ever I do, can't seem to resolve it. This is the function:

```
function initPlaylist() {

    //Get the playlists data from JSON
    $.get('json/playlists.json', function(data) {

        data.forEach(function(playlist) {

            //Create div for each playlist and populate it
            var album = $('<div>', {class: 'pl-singular-playlist'}).appendTo(playlistsContainer);

            //Playlist image
            $('<img>', {src: playlist.image}).appendTo(album);

            //Playlist button
            $('<button>', {
                'data-id': playlist.id,
                text: playlist.name,
                class: 'pl-play-button',
                click: function (e) {

                    //Show image in music player
                    $('<img>', {
                        src: playlist.image,
                        id: 'pl-selected-image'
                    }).appendTo(playerContainer);

                    //Set background image for the music player container
                    $(mainContainer).css('background-image', 'url(' + playlist.image + ')');
                    $(mainContainer).css('background-size', 'cover');
                    $(mainContainer).css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
                    $(mainContainer).css('background-position', 'center');

                    initAudio(e.currentTarget.dataset.id);
                }
            }).appendTo('.pl-singular-playlist');
        })
    })
}
```

This is the project I currently have so you could see how it looks (buttons show on hover):

https://aviadweiss.github.io/playlists/

Would appreciate your help

Comment: Can you show the json structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `.appendTo(div);` at the bottom.

As it stands, you're appending each button to *all* elements with the class `pl-singular-playlist`.